# Displaying <<..>>= in output

Tags: r, knitr

I want demonstrate a sample piece of R code WITH the knitr <<..>>= preamble in a LaTeX document.  Here is an example of the output I desire:

[image: snip-of-code]

It's got to be simple - but I'm missing something.  I checked the documentation and scanned stack overflow - but without luck. Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    <<mychunk, cache=TRUE, eval=FALSE, dpi=100>>=
    "hello world" 
    @
    \end{document}
```

Suggestions?  I tried indenting the code in LaTex and wrapping in a `verbatim` block, but only got errors.

Comment: Would a verbatim environment help?

Comment: @Lustrik - I tried `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` and got latex compilation errors.

Comment: That would be because it's still compiling the inline knitr code, and therefore trying to start a verbatim environment within a verbatim environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked the manual of knitr. This is how the package author solved the problem:

```
<<use-ext-chunk, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
cat('<<Q1, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=','@',sep='\n')
@
```

which produces the output as shown on page 9 of the knitr [manual](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf)

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}


<<use-ext-chunk, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
  cat('<<Q1, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=','@',sep='\n')
@

\end{document}
```

which produces the attached output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know where to look to see how the Knitr author did it.  I believe that I'll propose a new new chunk option, something like `display.wrapper=TRUE` so that the original chunk options are also embedded in the output.

Comment: That's a good proposal and Yihui is really helpful and open for new ideas. So just let him know what he thinks.

Comment: @JohnLeonard I absolutely love the proposal, and I myself feel painful to write `<<>>=` in tutorials as well!

Comment: @Yihui - I added the issue as a proposal to the Github knitr repository.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question on tex.stackexchange.com a year ago and got a few nice responses: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35485/3419. This is for `Sweave` but I think it will work the same in `knitr`.

I think I ended up just using `\Sexpr{"<<>>="}` and `\Sexpr{"@"}` in verbatim environment. e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\Sexpr{"<<mychunk, cache=TRUE, eval=FALSE, dpi=100>>="}
"hello world" 
\Sexpr{"@"}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a workable solution - but for Sweave not Knitr.  Knitr doesn't instance the `\Sexpr` environment.  Thanks!

Comment: @SachaEpskamp I just invented an evil method for moving other answers further down by just including a big, almost white page. Wasn't done on purpose here, so I hope you forgive me ;-) Btw: I'm gonna patent that solution, so please no copying...

Comment: @JohnLeonard I just tried the example above, and it also works with knitr.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick follow-up: this feature has been implemented in `knitr` ([devel version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/) >= 0.8.15); see examples for both [Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/062-chunk-wrapper.Rnw) and [Rmd](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/062-chunk-wrapper.md). An alternative solution is in [`knitr` FAQ](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md).